# loop for gathering 30 files

Tags: r, function, loops

Hi I am very new to loop functions. I want to be able to read through my 30 files and gather each of them. Then proceed using them.
In the first step I take a combined file and then split it into 30 files based on the term plate code. So the different plates each become a file named by their specific plate code. This bit works and I end up with 30 plate files.

```
    RickDADA2.split<- split.data.frame(RickDADA2, RickDADA2$platecode)
# Save
lapply(names(RickDADA2.split), function(x){
    write_csv(files[[x]], path = paste(x, ".csv", sep = ""))
    })
```

Then I read all 30 files back into R (this bit works as well) Each file as 5 columns, and what I need to be able to do is pull out 3 of those 5 columns and then spread them into wide format for each of the 30 files:

```
    files.name<-list.files(pattern='ASV.csv')
files.name.list<-list('vector', length(files.name))
files.name].list <- lapply(files.name, function(x) read_csv(x))
```

Then I need to be able to process the files in the following way, and I can't figure out how to write the loop to get it to work...When I try to do these two steps in the code using lapply they toss up the following error:

```
    files.name %>% unite('code2', c(platecode, code), remove=T, sep='_')
    files.name %>% spread(key='code2', value='abund', fill=0)
```

Thanks so much for your help with loop functions

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably (I can't be sure as you simply say "it won't work" and don't provide your input data) that `files[1-30]` is not a valid R variable name.

Try something like this: [untested code]

```
fileNames <- list.files(pattern='ASV.csv')
fileContents <- lapply(fileNames, read_csv)
finalResult <- lapply(
                 fileContents, 
                 function(x) {
                   x %>% 
                     unite('code2', c(platecode, code), remove=T, sep='_') %>%
                     spread(key='code2', value='abund', fill=0)
                 }
```

You could combine the final two steps into one with

```
finalResult <- lapply(
                 fileNames,
                 function(fName) {
                   read_csv(fName) %>% 
                     unite('code2', c(platecode, code), remove=T, sep='_') %>%
                     spread(key='code2', value='abund', fill=0)
                 }
```

Or do everything at once with

```
finalResult <- lapply(
                 list.files(pattern='ASV.csv'),
                 function(fName) {
                   read_csv(fName) %>% 
                     unite('code2', c(platecode, code), remove=T, sep='_') %>%
                     spread(key='code2', value='abund', fill=0)
                 }
```